# Structure with Lowevents and Freebie

Tags: structure, freebie, low-events

I can't get it work. Ik use structure, low events and freebie in a ee website.

My code looks like this:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}
{!-- --------------------------------- All agenda items ----------------------------------------------  --}
{case value="''"}

{exp:low_events:calendar channel="ch_agenda" date="{freebie_3}"}

{if '{prev_month format="%Y%m"}' >= '{current_time format="%Y%m"}'}
<a href="{path="actueel/agenda/{prev_month_url}"}" title="{prev_month format='%F %Y'}">
{exp:low_events:prev_date date="{freebie_3}" unit="month" format="%F %Y"}</a>{/if}


<a href="{path="actueel/agenda/{next_month_url}"}" title="{next_month format='%F %Y'}">
{next_month format="%F %Y"}</a>

<div class="maand">
{this_month format="%F %Y"}
</div>

{/exp:low_events:calendar}

{exp:low_events:entries channel="ch_agenda" date="{freebie_3}" unit="month" show_passed="no" no_results="yes"}

<h1><a href="{url_title_path='actueel/agenda'}">{title}</a></h1>
{agenda_datum:start_date format="%j %F %Y"}
{if '{agenda_datum:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}' > "{agenda_datum:start_date format='%j %F %Y'}"} tot {agenda_datum:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}{/if} {agenda_plaatst}
<br />

<a href="{page_url}">read more...</a>



{/exp:low_events:entries}

{/case}

{!-- --------------------------------- 1 detail item  ----------------------------------------------  --}
{case default="Yes"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="ch_agenda" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}

{if agenda_image != ""}<img src="{agenda_image:agendaopmaat}" width="500" alt="{title}">{/if}
<h1 class="agenda-titel">{title}</h1>
{agenda_datum:start_date format="%j %F %Y"}
{if '{agenda_datum:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}' > "{agenda_datum:start_date format='%j %F %Y'}"}
 tot {agenda_datum:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}{/if} {agenda_plaatst}
{agenda_tekst}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

When I go to agenda I get this URL and what I see is what I want.
http://site.nl/actueel/agenda/

In the Freebie settings I have as Breaking Segments: agenda

I did this to be able to use this link: `<a href="{path="actueel/agenda/{next_month_url}"}" title="{next_month format='%F %Y'}">` without problem with structure.
I get then this URL: http://site.nl/actueel/agenda/2014-11

But I have a problem with my read more… link: `<a href="{page_url}">read more...</a>`
I know it's because of my Freebie settings but how can I get de detail page to work.

Comment: Are you saying the {page_url} doesn't render correctly inside a low_events:entries tag?

Comment: No this not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only append segments to the end, so the details may not work if you're telling Freebie/Structure to ignore everything after agenda.

Comment: I agree with you but I can not find a way to get what I want. I have try with switchee, also no succes. It must be possible to use Structure with LowEvents and get a page detail. When I have something like that: .../agenda it is working perfect but if I have something like that ../agenda/2014-11 I got probleem with structure, I get a 404 page. That's why I try with Freebie and use agenda as breaking point but then I Can't get something like that: ...agenda/url_title

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need an url like this: site.nl/actueel/agenda/2014-11-1/url-title

- freebie_1: actueel
- freebie_2: agenda
- freebie_3: date
- freebie_4: url title

You could try to test the freebie segments with a nested switchee:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{freebie_4}" parse="inward"}
    {!-- start by checking the last possible segment --}
      {case value=''}
        {!-- ok, so freebie_4 is empty, now let's test the other segments
        {switchee variable="{freebie_3}"}
          {case value=''}
          {!-- Ok, freebie_3 is empty. this should be the agenda overview page--}
          {/case}
          {case default="Yes"}
            {!-- Ok, freebie_3 is not empty. this should be the month view --}
          {/case}
        {/switchee}
      {/case}
      {case default="Yes"}
      {!-- show the item --}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="ch_agenda" limit="1" dynamic="no" url_title="{freebie_4}"}
          {title}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
      {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
```

Since you are taking this all out of EE/Structure hierarchy, your page_url variable will not work properly anymore. Guess you will have to build the links manually like {site_url}actueel/agenda/date-segment/{url_title}/